# Вызов action у form из Requst

Tags: javascript, html, post, get, html-form

Добрый день!

В ответ на запрос, получаю `html` код страницы, в дальнейшем `index.html`. В ней содержится тег `form`, у которого атрибут `action` имеет определенный обработчик например `example.ru/doSomthing.php`, и на кнопке `submit` тоже есть некоторый обработчик.

Подскажите, как действовать, дальше для вызова этого метода или его выполнения. Не понимаю....у меня есть только `html` код, как с этим дальше быть. Сохранять в `html` и в нем искать по тегу и вызывать `click` у `submit`....или же я могу в ответ на запрос в `response` запихнуть что-то....что реализует или даст понять серверу, что сейчас должна выполниться обработка формы.

Реализацию `example.ru/doSomthing.php` не знаю, знаю что `index.html` содержит 2 поля и кнопку.

Comment: перепишите вопрос и добавьте туда код

Comment: XMLHttpRequest ?

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос путем использования nightmare js